# sycl/dpc++ accessor vs. global_ptr in kernel function object

Tags: sycl, dpc++, intel-oneapi

With the following toy code using Intel OneAPI beta6.

```
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace sycl = cl::sycl;

const int SIZE=1;

class Increment_accessor {
  public:
    Increment_accessor(sycl::accessor<int, 1, sycl::access::mode::read_write, sycl::access::target::global_buffer> ptr_) : ptr {ptr_} {}
    void operator()(sycl::item<1> item) {
      ptr[item.get_linear_id()]++;
    }
  private:
    sycl::accessor<int, 1, sycl::access::mode::read_write, sycl::access::target::global_buffer> ptr;
};

class Increment_pointer {
  public:
    Increment_pointer(sycl::global_ptr<int> ptr_) : ptr {ptr_} {} 
    void operator()(sycl::item<1> item) {
      ptr[item.get_linear_id()]++;
    }
  private:
    sycl::global_ptr<int> ptr;
};

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  sycl::device dev = sycl::default_selector().select_device();
  sycl::queue q(dev);
  int hbuffer[SIZE] = {};

  {
    sycl::buffer<int, 1> hbuf(hbuffer, sycl::range<1> {SIZE});
    q.submit([&](sycl::handler& cgh) {
        auto harray = hbuf.get_access<sycl::access::mode::read_write, sycl::access::target::global_buffer>(cgh);
        // !!! Uncomment _one_ of the following lines to compile !!!
        //Increment_accessor increment {harray};
        //Increment_pointer increment {harray};
        //Increment_pointer increment {harray.get_pointer()};
        cgh.parallel_for<class kernel1>(
            sycl::range<1> {SIZE}, 
            increment
        );
      }
      ); 
  }

  for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) std::cout << "hbuffer[" << i << "]= " << hbuffer[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Question: why are the Increment_pointer versions "wrong"?  There's no compile/runtime error. You just don't get the incremented hbuffer at the end.  (I've played with some similar versions where the ptr in operator() ends up being 0x0).

I'm still learning to think in "SYCL" so elaborating explanation is welcome.

Comment: This code you have provided doesn't compile, increment is not defined and I'm not sure what you are trying to do with it I'm afraid. Have you taken a look at some of the SYCL samples we provide on our GitHub repo? https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/computecpp-sdk/tree/master/samples

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  You need to uncomment one of the lines in the source to get the right function object.  I've edited the code to make that more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are asking why your code works when using `Increment_accessor` but breaks when using `Increment_pointer`. Or, phrased more generally, can a kernel function be built that that accepts pointers as arguments instead of accessors?

The SYCL spec is not super clear on this, but section 4.7.6.3 gives a hint:

> A  SYCL accessor can  be  a  device  accessor  in  which  case  it  provides  access  to  data  within  a  SYCL  kernel function, or a host accessor in which case it provides immediate access on the host. If  an accessor has  the  access  target access::target::global_buffer, access::target::constant_buffer, access::target::local,access::target::image or access::target::image_array then it is considered a device  accessor,  and  therefore  can  only  be  used  within  a  SYCL  kernel  function

So, device accessors are not valid on the host. Now, in your pointer-based versions, you are calling `get_pointer()` (or rely on an implicit conversion from accessor to pointer, which will be equivalent). But at that point, you are still inside the command group scope, *not inside the kernel*, i.e. the code inside the `parallel_for` `increment` kernel. The command group scope is always evaluated on the host in SYCL because the accessors constructed there tell the SYCL runtime  how to build the task graph and which dependencies nodes in the SYCL task graph have.

Therefore we can boil down the question to whether calling `get_pointer()` already qualifies as *using a device accessor*. If it does, it means that a device accessor is used outside a SYCL kernel which violates the cited section of the specification and would make this code illegal.

I would argue that calling `get_pointer()` already corresponds to "using an accessor". `get_pointer()` requires for example that the accessor already has a valid device memory allocation that it can point to. But, in command group scope it is possible that this allocation doesn't even exist yet since an efficient SYCL runtime might only do necessary allocations in device memory lazily in the background right before they are needed. But during command group evaluation, the command group is not even fully submitted yet to the SYCL runtime, as it is, in fact, still in the stage of *being submitted*. Therefore, a SYCL implementation will in general not be able to guarantee that `get_pointer()` already works at this stage.

It is therefore best to assume that device accessors on the host are merely a *description* of the accessed data and only gain more meaning as a mechanism that actually allows data accesses when used inside kernels.

Now, to the more general question whether it is possible to have kernels accept pointers as arguments instead of accessors: It is not possible in SYCL 1.2.1 in my understanding to have accessors and somehow convert them to pointers on the host because of the issues described above. But, if you don't use accessors at all, you can use the Intel [unified shared memory](https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/extensions/USM/USM.adoc) (USM) extension. This extension is not yet in regular SYCL 1.2.1, but it is available in Intel oneAPI DPC++. USM allows you to explicitly create device-accessible allocations that are managed using pointers. You can then use those pointers directly in your kernels.

Update: USM has been merged into the official SYCL 2020 standard which was released in Feb 2021, and is now available in multiple SYCL implementations apart from DPC++.

Comment: Now I understand.  Thanks for a wonderfully elucidating response.  Now that I understand I'm using the accessor in the wrong scope I kinda wonder whether the compiler and/or runtime should flag it as an error.  Anyway, stay tuned.  I'm having a hard time getting my mind around the hidden/implicit (and under described) behaviors in SYCL and expect I'll have more stackoverflow questions in the future.

Comment: Great! In a compiler-based SYCL implementation such as Intel DPC++, diagnosing such cases and printing an error or warning should be possible and sounds like a good idea. I would recommend you open an issue on https://github.com/intel/llvm and suggest this to the Intel DPC++ Devs. Note that there are SYCL implementations out there that rely on SYCL being pure C++ syntax and therefore implement SYCL as pure C++ library. For these implementations, printing such diagnostics is not possible since there is no SYCL-specific compiler support.

Comment: Interesting use case... I have created an internal issue for the spec in https://gitlab.khronos.org/sycl/Specification/issues/346